# where to put presentation data formatting method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a specially formatted dropdown list as part of a view. I have a controller action which fetches the data for the dropdown, then needs to format it by fetching certain other related data and putting it into a comma-separated format. This method is so far only used in this controller. The question is this: is it better to create a separate class and create a method in it which does this, or is it sufficient to create a separate method in the controller itself? The latter way seems simpler to me but wondering if I am defying the SRP.

Comment: I'd say don't overthink it for now, just put it into the Controller and reconsider it later if you need to use it somewhere else. I don't really think most Controllers adhere to SRP to begin with, since you usually add new methods to an existing controller to support brand new functionality.

Comment: I suggest you create a custom DisplayTemplate and use `@Html.DisplayFor()`. That way you're following convention and it will be obvious to other developers where the code is. [Here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523907/define-a-displaytemplate-for-a-custom-type).

Answer (score 1):

Isolating the conversion in its own static class makes DRY (don't repeat yourself) happier than SRP. I guess they are close relatives.

Usually, there is more than one place where view model is created. Having a single place where business object or DTO (data transfer object) turns into view model helps prevent certain bugs where fields are added and then someone forgot the one place where that class gets touched and you needed to copy that new field ...

[Automapper](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html) can help with that - it can automatically copies fields of the same name, and provides a convenient fluent API to express conversions.

It's all a little borderline. You can perfectly test a static function inside your controller. You don't absolutely require a library just create classes that are really similar to other classes you already have. All in all though it creates dead simple code that's hard to get wrong. Reducing complexity is a good habit to have.

Answer (score -2):

I'd put it in a separate class just to make it testable separately.

Comment: You need to flesh out your answer. As it stands, it doesn't answer some aspects of the original question, such as SRP.